# WPFToolkit.Extended RichTextBox run time format

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, richtextbox

I required to **format** text in `RichTextBox` at runtime, i.e. make selected text bold at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ApplyPropertyValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.applypropertyvalue.aspx) method:

```
TextSelection selection = yourRichTextBox.Selection;
if (!selection.IsEmpty) {
    selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty,
        FontWeights.Bold);
}
```